# I can not calculate length of disk queue in Linux

Tags: linux, monitoring, disk

I do not need to use any side tool like "iostat". I need to calculate length of the disk queue by raw data, which can be gathered from "/proc/diskstats" for example.

I investigated the source code of **iostat** utility to get the way it use to calculate average disk queue length. The utility uses 11-th field of "*/sys/block/<device>/stat*" file. This field stands for "*weighted time spent doing I/Os (ms)*". The utility calculates time derivative of the field. I tried to calculate it by myself and compare the result with "iostat" output. I have got different values. What a did:

1. Execute command "*cat /sys/block/sda/stat & iostat -x*";
2. Wait for 10 seconds;
3. Execute command "*cat /sys/block/sda/stat & iostat -x*";
4. Calculate the difference between the 11-th field of "*/sys/block/sda/stat*" file and divide the result by 10 and then to 1000 (because of milliseconds);
5. Compare the result with the last output of "*iostat -x*" command.

Also, I tried to search sources, which could give out information about I/O operations, but I found only information about the amount of I/O operations executed in real-time. Unfortunately, it is not enough to calculate a disk queue length or an average disk queue length.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little's_law

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please include it in the question, and add the appropriate tag (probably [tag:shell], judging from your description).

Comment: @TobySpeight, what code do you mean? I do not have any code in my question.

Comment: What's that in your list then?  If you're not writing some code, then perhaps Stack Overflow isn't the right place - consider [unix.se] instead.

Comment: I've edited tags, since it appears you want to access this information from user space.  If you are indeed working inside the kernel, then please make that clearer.

Comment: @TobySpeight, my list contains actions, which I did. Some of these actions contain calling the "cat" utility, there is not code. I am seen to ask a help in not right place. I thought "StackOverflow" is for any type of question. Thank you for directing me.

Comment: @stark, thank you for answering. I read the article but still can not calculate the queue. I need to know the average pending time to calculate the queue. Do you know where it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my algorithm of calculation was right. I just had to make some load on disk (e.g. copy a big file) to see difference. If someone would try to compare your own result with the output of "iostat", then you better run two terminals because of convenience. One terminal for reading file "/proc/diskstats" and the other terminal for executing "iostat -x 10" (where 10 is how often data updates in seconds).

Comment: On my Linux Mint 21.2 Xfce system (Linux kernel 5.15.0-76-generic x86_64) `file:///sys/block/sda/stat` gives `63433    46587  3537003   475817    31960    38447  1986258   125489        0   216904   623052        0        0        0        0    10246    21745` a total of 17 values, not 11 ... I have tried to find out online their meaning, but failed ( https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt lists meaning of 11 values, not 17). Hmmm ...